# Three fragments in one one activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

New to Android, and I'm trying  to make an app that displays a name list, then to the right a topic heading on the right of that, and then a third fragment that displays details on that topic heading. I'd like for all three fragments to diplay on my main activity. So I want it to look like this:

[Paint description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INoCA.jpg)

So far this is the main xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/companyListFrag_LL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        class= "name.financialnews.CompaniesListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/list_companies"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_headings"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/list_headings"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

When I run this, Im able to click on name to get topic heading on the right and when i click topic heading, nothing shows up for the detail fragment. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thank You

here is the detail fragment xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/textHeading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />

</FrameLayout>
```

added main activity java:

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements CompaniesListFragment.OnCompaniesSelectedListener,
    HeadingsListFragment.OnHeadingsSelectedListener

{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


public void onCompanySelected(long id){


    HeadingsListFragment headingsList = new HeadingsListFragment();

    FragmentTransaction transaction= 
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    headingsList.updateCompanyId(id);

    transaction.replace(R.id.list_headings,headingsList);

    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);

    transaction.commit();


}


@Override
public void onHeadingSelected(long id) {


    Detail_Fragment items = new Detail_Fragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=            
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    items.updateHeadingId(id);


    transaction.replace(R.id.detail_fragment, items);

    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);

    transaction.commit();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the root element from a RelativeLayout to a LinearLayout and change the orientation of it to vertical. I would also put a weight on the inner LinearLayout so that both direct children of the root element have equal weights. The space you are giving to the companies list and the headings is also very small (20dp is not very big).

When I paste your code into Android Studio, there are warnings that state a few problems with your layout that would have pointed you in the right direction. Overall, I recommend starting simple and adding one fragment at a time. One thing that can help is to turn on the setting "show layout bounds" in the developer options if you are having trouble with view layouts.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I changed what you asked and it still isnt showing me the third fragment on the bottom. Everything else shows up fine.

Comment: I cannot help you with that fragment because it is not in the layout xml. I assume you are adding a detail fragment to the frame layout in java code.

Comment: i'll add the other fragment to the main post

Comment: Like I said before, how is the detail fragment getting inserted into the main layout?

Comment: my apologies, i added the java code for main activity

Comment: First, make sure that the onHeadingSelected is being called properly. Then make sure that the FrameLayout that it is being placed into has room. If you still have the width as 0dp, then there is no room. Change the width to match_parent and, again, make sure that it has a weight so that it gets height (weight gives it height because it should be in a vertical LinearLayout at this point).

Comment: Also, I think your TextViews in the detail fragment layout are placed on top of each other since they are in a FrameLayout.